# Protocol design

Tags: android, xml, protocols, protocol-buffers

I have a client server program to communicate the pc with an android phone using usb, based on http://www.anothem.net/archives/2010/10/15/android-usb-connection-to-pc/

Now I need to design a protocol that facilitates information exchange from the pc to the phone. How should I go about this ? Should we use XML for this? I was looking at google protocol buffer.. Is that the right direction ?

Thanks
Caroline

Comment: How complex is the data you want to transport? Do you want others to use your protocol as well?

Comment: The data would be commands like click, touch etc...i was thinking more in lines of a protocol that is specific to this application..so I'm not sure if it would be useful to others.

Comment: In this case, you should listen to @kgiannakakis - his suggestion mashes with how I see things :-) If you want to send some more complex data later on, you can sniff at google protocol buffer, or just use json. Since this is your own application, you don't need to use the same protocol for all your requests. Keep the simple one simples and the complex ones, well complex :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need first to design the higher layer of your protocol. Xml and protocol buffers have to do with how the data are formatted. Depending on the data you need to exchange they may or not be suitable. From what you way in your comment, it seems that you want to develop something like a remote control for your PC. In that case both XML and Google Protocol Buffers will be an overdesign. Simply create a text protocol, allocate a byte or two for the command type and some bytes for the data body.

Have a look at the [AT commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) structure. The structure of an [HDLC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-Level_Data_Link_Control) frame could also give you some ideas. This has some things like error checking, which you don't need, but other than that a simple text protocol will use similar fields.

Comment: thanks for that..but could you please tell me where to look at in order to create a text protocol. I was unable to find any pointers..

Answer (score 4):

I've been using protocol buffers on Android.  I avoided it for a long time, reasoning that it was overkill.  That was before I took half a day to try it out.

Here were my results, after spending an afternoon on it.  At first it increased my APK size from 2.89megs to 3.1 megs.  I consider that inconsequential.  Then I found that I was able to delete code I had all over the place, where I had been doing parsing manually.  I was able to delete code that required the data to come in in a specific sequence.

Then I was able to completely delete a few classes I had in my application, whose purpose was to serve as temporary, lightweight information-only "model" classes that represented data coming to or from the data stream.  In short, it started making things way easier and smaller, and more reliable.

Protocol Buffers may well be not the best thing for your situation.  But I do recommend that you take a few hours and try it out.  That way you'll be making your decision to leave it behind from a position of strength and knowledge.

Be sure to use the lite version of protocol buffers.  The .jar file is 160k, but the amount of functionality it brings is huge.  I'll be using it all the time from here on out.

I do have some concerns about dynamic memory allocation / garbage collection when using it in a game context long term.  But for now the serialization happens infrequently enough that it's a non-issue for me.

Another bonus: I have some Python code that generates data files that the application reads.  That python code processes some XML and then generates binary files.  I think I'll be able to completely eliminate that code by using protocol buffer's text mode, then using protoc directly to create binary files.